# Making sense of the radius units from the smallest-circle challenge

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geometry, geospatial

I am using the solution at http://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle to solve the smallest circle problem. However, instead of specifying `x` and `y`, I provide a longitude and latitude.

However, the units returned do not make any sense:

```
2015-04-29 23:25:05 - info: Generated activity model: {"x":49.2080275,"y":-2.1146475000000002,"r":0.017797481240332452}
// Where x=lat, y=lng
```

The solution is designed to return the same generic units used for the positions, however in this scenario it means it returns the radius in degrees (?) which doesn't make any sense.

For mapping, I need to calculate the radius in meters, but you cannot convert between degrees and meters, so the whole problem seems a little absurd.

Could someone point me in the right direction, or at least give a second opinion on actually using the data returned?

Answer (score 0):

Most formulas calculating the great-circle-distance give the distance in degrees. On the earth's surface 1° equals 60 nautical miles. One nautical mile equals 1852 meters.

E.g. a distance of 180° means half the circumference of the earth.

Comment: Well, yes and no. On a spherical earth, at the equator a degree of longitude and a degree of latitude are indeed 1 nautical mile. However the size of a degree of longitude scales with the cosine of the latitude.